# jQuery slider next prev button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jsfiddle

I'm trying to make a simple slider with prev and next buttons. The slider works fine and the next button functions alright, but as you can see the prev button is wonky:

```
invNext.on('click', function PreviousPic() {

  var currentPic = $('.img-nav-container > img');
  $(currentPic).fadeOut(1000, function () {

    // fadeIn the previous image in the array
    var img = imgArr[(currIndex - 1)]; // not working
    $("#slider").attr("src", img);
    GetNewImage();
    $("#slider").fadeIn(1000);

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpm/5TsL6/

I made a jsfiddle since it will be more helpful to see everything thats going on. 
What am I missing? Also, I'd appreciate any help refactoring this mess. I'm still very much a newbie with jQuery...

Thanks in advance,

-D

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
invNext.on('click', function PreviousPic() {

  var currentPic = $('.img-nav-container > img');
  $(currentPic).fadeOut(1000, function () {

    // fadeIn the previous image in the array
    var img = imgArr[(currIndex - 2)]; // not working
    $("#slider").attr("src", img);
    GetNewImage();
    $("#slider").fadeIn(1000);

  });
```

Comment: hey HB, I tried that already with no luck, I even gave it a go right now and it didn't work still. It just keeps reloading the same image.